# How to not destroy current activity when back is presse

Tags: android, android-activity

I couldn't find any answers on this, and I am a little lost.  I have two activities, Act1 and Act2.  I have a button in Act1 that starts a new intent to Act2 when it is pressed.  However whenever i hit the back button while in Act2, than click the button again is restarts a new Intent.

i do not want it to do that... i want it to resume Act2.  How can I go about doing it? Thanks in advance/

Comment: you may be asking the wrong question.  tell us what you want to achieve and there is probably a way around it rather than just wanting to `resume` Act2.  do you want to save some sort of state/values of Activity 2 so when you come back they will be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is android default behavior when you click on return(escape) or back button,it finishes the current activity and loads the previous activity.If you do not want the default behavior you can override the onKeyDown method it will help you.See the example code in the following doc URL
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
Are you doing any network or similar operations in Act2 which you do not want do next time?

Comment: yes sir, i am doing some networking in act2 that i want to save unless the user wants to refresh.

Comment: then put a flag in Act2 which indicates that the data is downloaded,so you can check the flag every time and make your operation,you can save this flag in database or use shared preferences to save the flag.

Answer (score 4):

You could set the launch mode to "singleTop" as described in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) and catch the back button presses to start a new Intent, that will reveal the old activity because they are singleTop.

```
<activity android:name=".Act1" android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
<activity android:name=".Act2" android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the onPause method in Act2 and save your info in a SharedPreferences object, which would be retrieved in the onCreate() on returning.